# Typescript automatic generic type without explicitly declare the type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

If I have an interface with two functions. one function returns a value. I want to use the type of value in another function in the same interface. I did use generics but I have to explicitly declare the type every time I create new object. but It could be done without it. For example:

```
interface MyObject<T> {
    create(): T
    update(value: T): void // use value type defined in create method
}
```

and here we define new object using the interface above:

```
let test: MyObject<string> = {
    create() {
        return "Hello"
    },
    update(value) {
        // do something with value
    },
}
```

It's possible to write `MyObject` without `<string>`. as the value type already been defined in `create` method?

Comment: Note that non-primitive type names conventionally begin with an uppercase character, as in `MyObject`, as opposed to `myObject`.

Comment: I have removed my answer in favor of @jcalz 's answer, mine was with some unnecesary overhead

Comment: @captain-yossarian it's unrelated answer

Comment: What I want It's not about object creation but I want omit `<type>` in the generic and automatically use the type from `create` method. to avoid writing unnecessary code and make things more clean.

Comment: @jcalz that convention for naming classes or anything could be instantiated. In my example yeah I could use this convention . but with other object. name it like any other variable

Comment: Naming conventions are of course just conventions, and so there may be some differences across different groups of developers.  That being said, I have considerable experience looking at TypeScript code and libraries, and an interface almost never starts with an lowercase letter for any standard or popular libraries.  If you don't want to confuse people, you should consider starting your interface names with an uppercase character.

Comment: @jcalz Yeah already aware of this and I use it of course. but in this example I wrote it quickly so I missed it. anyways let's focus on the question topic

Comment: Well, you could edit your question to make the naming more conventional, and then I can remove the part of my answer that refers to naming conventions and indeed all my comments about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would like the compiler to *infer* `string` for the generic type parameter `T`.  The only place such [generic type parameter inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#inference) occurs is when you call a generic function, so if you want this behavior you will need to refactor from a type annotation (`const test: MyObject<string> = ...`) to calling a helper function (`const test = toMyObject(...)`).

### Update for TS4.7+:

It looks like [microsoft/TypeScript#48358](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/48538) will be released with TypeScript 4.7, at which point the compiler will indeed be able to contextually type method parameters from type parameters inferred from previously defined properties.  At that point the following will work:

```
const toMyObject = <T,>(o: MyObject<T>) => o;

let test = toMyObject({
    create() {
        return "Hello"
    },
    update(value) {
        value.toUpperCase()
    },
})
```

Note that this depends on the order of the members of the object literal, so because you need `T` inferred from `create()` before you can use it in `update()`, you need `create()` to be earlier than `update()` in the object.  So the following breaks:

```
let test2 = toMyObject({
    update(value) {
        value.toUpperCase() // error
    },
    create() {
        return "Hello"
    },
});
```

[Playground link for TS4.7+](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.0-dev.20220406#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMAHgBUA+ZAbwChk7kEoI5IAKASgC5kTb6BXAA4ATFhFYA3OABt+EbiS7IJAe2DDqAX2rUEKkAGcwyMCow58hZAF5kpADRlWK7ubwFi5djYoqA3DrSEMaQRjYmZljuhKw09AxMYhxUfPF0TGD8UCDIAEQAEhDS0iq5qcia9uVComxSshDecWl09XIAdKYAqoKC0ADCcAbi7OWVWqPUQSEQRgBM4aZulmCx1SJJbY0pLa0yHd29A0MjyAD0Z8jQUCpQY1XxjMxsTeXxGVk5BUUlZfHjmnYfiAA)

---

### Previous answer for TS4.6-:

Furthermore, you want the compiler to infer the type of the `value` callback parameter of the `update` method.  This type of inference is called [contextual typing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing).

Unfortunately, contextual type inference of callback parameters and generic type parameter inference do not play well together when both depend on the same object.  This is a design limitation of TypeScript. See [microsoft/TypeScript#38872](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38872) for more information.

In order to get both contextual type inference and generic type parameter inference then, your helper function will need to split the input object into two pieces: one for `create` so that the generic type parameter `T` can be inferred, and the other for `update` so that the callback parameter `value`'s type can be inferred.

That gives us this:

```
const toMyObject = <T,>(
    create: () => T,
    update: (value: T) => void
): MyObject<T> => ({ create, update });
```

---

Let's test it:

```
let test = toMyObject(
    () => { return "Hello" },
    (value) => { console.log(value.toUpperCase()); }
);
// let test: MyObject<string>
```

Looks good.  The compiler infers that `test` is of type `MyObject<string>` as desired, and the callback parameter `value` is also inferred as `string` (as evidenced by the fact that you can call `value.toUpperCase()` without error in `--strict` mode).

[Playground link to code for TS4.6-](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3&ssl=16&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8DyAjAVhBMAHgBUA+ZAbwChk7kEoI5IAKASgC5kTb6BXAA4ATFhFYA3OABt+EbiS7IJAe2DDqAX2rUEKkAGcwyMCow58hZAF5kpADRlWfOo2aRuHGxRL2XyIVEPZEkZOQV2b2U1DSVzPAJicijWSgYmMXsAkTFkTXYAbh1pCGNIIxsTMywEwmd6EMjrCjSmMH4oEGQAIgAJCGlpFW68vwbQ2QgmloZ9AxUSgDohgHMJuUXTAFVBQWgAYTgDcXZCvOpC6gB6K+QSsogjbnjLYiMoUBWyaiA)

Comment: Thanks. But it's still duplicating code in function parameters. In my opinion it's less clean than using generic argument itself. I have more methods in real code. so I'll avoid that

Comment: You may indeed prefer to specify the generic type parameter yourself. But "duplicating code in function parameters" only happens once, in the function definition, and then you can use it as many times as you want without further duplication. Whether or not the single function definition is too much overhead depends on how many of these objects you are creating. In any case, there is no other way currently to get the compiler to infer both the generic `T` and the type of `value`, so possible answers are either this one or unfortunately "no, you can't do this".

Comment: Hi @jcalz, could you please provide me with your answers related to TypeScript 4.7 ? I'm interested in all hacks ) Unfortunatelly, I don't have a time to follow TS changes. Thank you