# Typescript generic extends show error message. (unexpected token, ...)

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to extends Union type. But, it show me an error message.

In other project, there is no problem.

Are there anyone who know about this error?

```
type Foobar = 'foo' | 'bar';

interface OptionProps<T extends Foobar> {
                        ~~~~~~~ // Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","
                                   1 | type Fb = 'foo' | 'bar';
                                   2 |
                                 > 3 | interface OptionProps<T extends Fb> {
                                     |                         ^
                                   4 |   value: T;
                                   5 |   setValue: (value: T) => void;
                                   6 | }eslint

  value: T;
  setValue: (value: T) => void;
}
```

Comment: It works perfectly fine https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nARgQwE5QLxQOQDMHZQA+OKq2A3AFBUCWAdsBKrsgMbQDyYwtc9ABVRwwAZwA8AFSgQAHk3oATUbARkAfFADeVKFABuyADYBXCAC4ok6ntERgANWNnLACkOmLVgJSZN+uFpFagBfGiA

Comment: You might be interested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66747117/typescript-automatic-generic-type-without-explicitly-declare-the-type

Comment: That's a weird error; please consider trying to produce a [mcve] that can be demonstrated to others.  My guess is that your IDE or project is not configured properly, but it's hard to advise without more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `eslintrc.json` check that you have `parser` set to this:

```
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
```

If its set up right just delete `node_modules` and run `npm install`.

```
rm -rf node_modules/
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

I see no error when using it

```
type Foobar = 'foo' | 'bar';

interface OptionProps<T extends Foobar> { 
  value: T;
  setValue: (value: T) => void;
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nARgQwE5QLxQOQDMHZQA+OKq2A3AFBUCWAdsBKrsgMbQDyYwtc9ABVRwwAZwA8AFSgQAHk3oATUbARkAfFADeUKlCgA3ZABsArhABcUSdX2iIwAGonzVgBRGzl6wEpMmgzhaRWoAXyA)

Try re-compiling your code